# How to check multiple keys in a Hash in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to figure out a way of storing multiple keys in a hash without making it a layered. I know how to iterate through a layered hash, but is there any from the example below?

Should I use `my %Hash={value1, value2}{Value3}` to get just value1? These two values need to be coupled and to have a layered hash like `{value1}{value2}{value3}` seems way to complicated.

So far, when I do `$Hash{$_ }` I get both `value1` and `value2` together, but for my purposes I need to check if either `value1`, `value2`, or both is present and do an `if` statement depending on which one is there.

Answer (score 1):

`$hash{$k1}{$k2}` makes no sense since you want to look up by `$k1` and by `$k2` independently. They have no relation to each other. So, your structure is obviously going to be

```
$hash{$k} = $val;
```

so your check will be

```
if ($hash{$k1} && $hash{$k2}) {
   ...
}
elsif ($hash{$k1}) {
   ...
}
elsif ($hash{$k2}) {
   ...
}
```

(You might have to used `exists($hash{...})` or `defined($hash{...})` depending on your data.)

Comment: is there anyway to assign just value 1 to a seperate variable and not the second?

Comment: huh? There's no assignment in there.

Comment: Im refering to my initial question

Comment: No assignment in there either. ("I need to check if either value1, value2, or both is present and do an if statement depending on which on is there.") By the way, it's best not to use the word "value" to refer to keys!

Comment: Oh sorry, basically I'm asking if I have a %Hash=($key1,$key2) can I assign a variable that just equals $key1

Comment: That makes no sense. You don't assign/store keys to/in a hash, and you don't fetch a key from a hash. Hashes store *values* indexed by *keys*. I can't make heads or tail of what you're asking in your last comment.

Comment: If you really have `%Hash=($key1,$key2)`, then you have a hash with one element, and you want the key of that element. That's a really silly thing to do, but it can be done using `my $x = (keys(%hash))[0];` or `my ($x) = keys(%hash);`. But I have a feeling you actually meant something very very different.